# PHPmailer DATA not accepted from server: 421

Tags: phpmailer

if i send single line message using PHPmailer it goes with out any error.

but if I send big message (10 lines)  i got following error ::.

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.5.0 Address Ok.
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 <toaddress>@gmail.com OK.
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Enter mail, end with a single ".".
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:421 4.4.2 Timeout while waiting for command.
SMTP -> ERROR: DATA not accepted from server: 421 4.4.2 Timeout while waiting for command.
SMTP Error: Data not accepted.
```

Answer (score 0):

That's about your `timeout` value. Find the following code in your class.phpmailer.php

`var $Timeout = 10;`

Then change the value to higher value.